# Problemas con INSERT desde PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, csv, insert

Les comento mi problema:

Yo tengo un archivo csv con cierta cantidad de datos, lo que hago es abrir dicho archivo y modificar unos campos que estan mal cargados (Telefonos con espacios, guiones, etc..) y luego los tengo que cargar en mi base de datos de postgress:

```
    #!/usr/bin/php
<?php
// Me conecto al pgsql
$conectarse = pg_connect(******);

// Reviso si la conexion fue exitosa sino devuelvo un error
if (!$conectarse) {die("Error de Conexion!: " . pg_last_error());}


// --- FUNCIONES --- ///

// Reemplaza los guiones bajo por espacios.
function sacar_guiones($var){
$reemplazo=str_replace("_", " ", $var);
return $reemplazo;
}

// Toma todo el string y solo deja los numeros y en caso de que no devuelva nada (devuelve 0 si no hay numeros) lo reemplaza por nada.
function telefono($numero) {
    $r = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $numero), 10);
    if($r == 0){$r = "";}
return $r;
}

// --- FIN FUNCIONES --- ///



// --- PROGRAMA PRINCIPAL --- ///


// Ignora las advertencias de PHP
error_reporting(0);

// Abro el archivo CSV en modo lectura
$file = fopen('datos-ejemplo.csv', 'r');

// Creo una bandera que utilizo para ignorar la primer vuelta asi no me guarda los cabezales
$band = 0;


// Recorro el archivo
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {

    // Consulto si es el primer ingreso, para evitar leer las cabeceras, si lo es cambio la bandera a 1 
    if($band != 0 )
        {

            // Almaceno los datos recolectados
            $RAZON=$line[14];   
            $LOCALIDAD=$line[16];   
            $EMAIL=$line[15];   
            $FECHADEREGISTRO=$line[1];
            $TELEFONO1=telefono($line[12]);
            $TELEFONO2=telefono($line[13]);

            // Genero la consulta SQL
            $query = "INSERT INTO tabla_datos (razon) VALUES ('" .$RAZON. "')";

            // Ejecuto la consulta
            $result = pg_query_params($conectarse, $query);

            // Verifico si la consulta se llevo a cabo correctamente, sino aviso
            if (!$result) die("\nError in SQL query: " . pg_last_error() . "\n");
        }
    else
        $band = 1;

    // fin del if   

} // end-while


// Cierro el archivo
fclose($file);


// Termino la conexion
pg_close($conectarse);
?>
```

La conexion se hace correctamente, pero a la hora de hacer un insert me da el siguiente error: "Error in SQL query:" es decir, el mensaje de error que tengo por si falla la query pero no me da informacion de porque falla

Alguien sabe que puede ser lo que este fallando? estuve todo el dia tratando de hacerlo andar y no pude =(

Gracias!

EDIT: Si intento hacer el insert con int si me lo toma, el problema esta en el date y el string

Comment: revisaste que tus variables realmente tengan datos? y que tus columnas tengan el tipo de dato que intentas agregar?

Comment: que dice el mensaje de error completo?

Comment: No llego a captar la lógica del código en esta parte: `} else $band = 1;`. ¿No será que hay una confusión en el flujo? Comenta temporalmente la parte de SQL poniendo simplemente un `echo $RAZON.PHP_EOL;` para ver qué pasa.

Comment: @A.Cedano Hola! Esa bandera es por que la primer linea que me lee son los cabezales del archivo csv (Los títulos de las columnas) entonces arme eso para esquivarlos

Comment: @A.Cedano el query impreso es el siguiente: INSERT INTO tabla_datos (razon) VALUES ('David Tennant')  por lo cual es correcto!

Comment: @CarolMirabal Hola! Si, es mas, a la variable $RAZON le hardcodee el nombre para comprobar si no era problema de tipo de dato y nada (N)

Comment: @Alfredo para capturar el error uso **pg_last_error()** pero no me esta dando ningun mensaje

Comment: Juan, el hecho de que la consulta no tenga errores de sintaxis no significa que sea *correcta*. Una consulta puede violar restricciones de la tabla, por ejemplo, si ya existe un `David Tennan` y hay un restricción `UNIQUE` en la columna `razon`, la consulta fallará porque se intenta crear un registro duplicado. Este es uno de los olvidos más grandes de los programadores: **no controlan los duplicados cuando trabajan con bases de datos**.  Hay otros motivos por los que esa consulta también fallaría, un ejemplo: si hubiera otra columna que no admita nulos y no tenga un valor por defecto.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano eso fue lo primero que revise! La tabla en el unico campo que no acepta nulos es en el id que es autoincremental, por lo que esta bien..respecto a restricciones del tipo unique no hay ninguna!

Comment: ¿Si ejecutas esta consulta `INSERT INTO tabla_datos (razon) VALUES ('David Tennant') ` directamente en el manejador la inserción se hace correctamente? Otra cosa que estoy viendo ahora es que tu código está dentro de funciones, pero no se ve desde dónde llamas a esas funciones para que se ejecuten.

Comment: @A.Cedano Nono el codigo no esta dentro de funciones, tiene una funcion que la uso en las variables TELEFONO1 y TELEFONO2 para sacar cualquier cosa que no sean numeros... si hago el insert directamente funciona! otra cosa que note es que si yo hago $razon = 'dato'; y trato de hacer el insert me lo toma perfecto... se me ocurrio como recurso para safar agregarle comillas simples a las variables y listo, total, ese csv despues de grabarlo en la DB se borra

Comment: No entiendo bien tu comentario. Según has dicho ya el insert se creaba con las comillas simples, por lo que el fallo no podía ser a causa de las comillas.

Comment: Claro, si yo hardcodeo un texto con comillas va de lujo, pero cuando quiero ponerlo en el insert da el error que me viene dando siempre...vi que viste el CSV, no tiene nada raro, es un csv comun y corriente, eso es lo raro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar imprimir la variable `$query` y probar el select dentro del programa pgAdmin.

Antes de agregar un select a codigo, asegurate de que funciona dentro del pgAdmin.

Comment: Hola! Si, eso mismo hice! Agarre la consulta y la mostre con un echo y la copie textual y la puse en el pgadmin y me la tomo perfecto! eso es lo raro

Comment: Probablemente estas insertando el date en un formato incorrecto. Ayudaria que compartieras un ejemplo del csv que intentas guardar y de la estructura de la tabla. Saludos.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FlwFQXLnXeTgIuJ0t5EHDGhImy2WR6wR/view?usp=sharing Este seria el CSV!

Comment: Estuve leyendo los demás comentarios y sólo se me ocurre que sea un problema de tamaño. ¿Ya corroboraste que el tamaño de la cadena que admite la tabla es mayor o igual a 'David Tennant' ?

Comment: Encontre el problema!! es que el CSV de facebook tiene una codificacion tipo Europa Occidental, entonces cuando yo veo la variable esta perfecta, pero cuando quiero insertarla en una base de datos, que tiene UTF-8 de codificacion, explota todo...tengo que encontrar la manera de que me acepte o modificar la codificacion que usa

Comment: Bastante interesante. Me alegro que hayas podido encontrar el problema. Se me ocurre que puedes cambiar la codificación directamente en tu tabla, encontre algunos enlaces que pueden ayudarte. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/5091083/9665053 -https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/multibyte.html